# Eclipse Javascript Plugin extension

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to creating plugins. I want to create an eclipse plugin for a new scripting language. And, its syntax is quite similar to JavaScript. So, I wish to extend existing Javascript plugin that exists in eclipse.

Please suggest how do I go about it. Mainly, I want to have editor functionality (syntax checking, auto completion and ctrl-click to go to hop across functions), no compiler/build is needed.

Also, where do I find the source code for existing JavaScript plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the JavaScript editor can be found in the `http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/kepler/` repository (assuming Eclipse Kepler). Look for the `JavaScript Development Tools SDK`.

You install this in to Eclipse using `Help > Install New Software` and the source is then available to read using `Navigate > Open Type` (you need to have `Include all plug-ins from target in Java search` selected in `Preferences > Plug-in Development` for this).

Eclipse editor code is very complex and it likely to be hard work to adapt it. You might find it easier to use something like [Eclipse xText](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.tmf.xtext) which is designed for developing support for new languages.